# Content export and import / content deployment

Tags: 8, nodes, importing-exporting, deployment

It's easy to deploy configuration of content types, views and so on...

What are the options for deployment of content (nodes) between different environments?

Answer (score 3):

The [Default Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content) module uses cores REST/HAL/Serialisation API's to export content to JSON. You put the content into you_module/content/[entity_type]/anything.json and the content is automatically imported when you enable your module.

Answer (score 1):

Historically you had options such as leveraging the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module or [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to achieve this (Migrate introduced the idea of *continuous migration of content*). While this would still be viable options (once contrib is ready), it seems the common preferred approach nowadays would be to have a 'content hub' from which you can pull content to various sites over RESTful web services. By leveraging [Drupal 8's RESTful capabilities](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/rest), you can totally define a deployment strategy over JSON/HAL+JSON, granted you'd lock down authentication/permissions enough to not expose your content to unprivileged resources.

Answer (score 0):

Also see the [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) module:

> The Deploy module is designed to allow users to easily stage and preview content for a Drupal site. Deploy automatically manages dependencies between entities (like node references).

This [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRmLEwStNjY) shows it's amazing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

For continuous content deployment not using [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy)'s Web services, there's [Content Synchronization](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync).

> The content synchronization module provides a mechanism to export single content items, or all content items, from an environment, and move them to another, effortlessly.